# How to create css code that works for all browser?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

i just wrote a css program , but when i emulate it in the version of 8,9 of internet explorer it didn't work correctly
,this is my code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #main {
                background-color:black;
                width:1020px;
                margin:0 auto;
                padding:0;
                overflow:hidden;
                resize:none;
            }
            #s {
                float:right;
                background-color:red;
                margin-right:8px;
                margin-top:8px;
                margin-bottom:8px;
                width:1000px;
                height:290px;
                overflow:hidden;
                border:2px solid yellow;
            }
            #k {
                float:right;
                background-color:green;
                margin-bottom:8px;
                margin-right:8px;
                width:500;
                height:300;
                overflow:hidden;
                border:2px solid yellow;
            }
            #v {
                background-color:grey;
                margin-right:10px;
                float:right;
                width:486;
                height:143;
                overflow:hidden;
                border:2px solid yellow;
            }
            #d {
                background-color:blue;
                margin-right:10px;
                margin-bottom:10px;
                float:right;
                width:486;
                height:143;
                overflow:hidden;
                border:2px solid yellow;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="s">salam</div>
            <div id="k">one</div>
            <div id="d">two</div>
            <div id="v">three</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my code,but when i emulate it in IE,in version of 8 , it works wrong, how can i fix this code to work correctly in all version of IE and another browsers?where is my problem?
in all browsers my css layout is in the center of page, but in IE8,9 my layout is in the left side of page,the margin of main layout i think,and when i add this "  " and emulate it with IE my layout change incorrectly

Comment: Define "didn't work correctly" and "works wrong". What exactly is the issue? The more detail, the better.

Comment: @ajp15243 in all browser except IE 8,9 the whole of my layout is in the center of page, but in IE 8,9 it is in the left side of page

Comment: The [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize) CSS property (which you use on `#main`) is not supported in IE. Try removing that to see if that fixes it. As @MiniRagnarok says, also add a `<!DOCTYPE html>`. This is likely your issue.

Comment: Don't forget to add a DOCTYPE.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok how to add it?

Comment: @zandkazem `DOCTYPE` should be the absolute very first thing in your HTML, before the `<html>` element.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>    -------   for HTML%

Comment: Welcome to the world of hating IE as it doesn't render css properly!  You may want to look into using [conditional IE stylesheets](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Comment: @UID when i add <doctype> my program didn't work correctly even in chrome browser,please save my code in a html text,and open it with browser

Comment: @Pete No Pete, just no. There's nothing special about his code other than the resize property and it's not doing anything. Conditional stylesheets are overkill here.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok W3Schools isn't always reliable or up-to-date. The [W3C wiki page for `DOCTYPE`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Doctypes_and_markup_styles) would be a better reference.

Comment: @Pete run my code in a .html file, when i added the docype, my whole program didn't work correctly even in chrome

Comment: @ajp15243 That wiki page is convoluted for a beginner. The W3Schools link is concise and to the point. While it's true that W3Schools isn't the best reference, it works great here.

Comment: @zandkazem It is overwhelmingly recommended to keep a `DOCTYPE` in your HTML, otherwise you will risk having browsers run outdated, deprecated, or otherwise non-standard code in rendering your page. Describe how it "didn't work correctly" more specifically with a `DOCTYPE`. [Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/15kjnp8g/) of your code.

Comment: @ajp15243 if you run my code in .html you will find out,i dont know how can i explain it

Comment: @ajp15243 it is wrong,you can see what i did here,[link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2zi7uh2&s=8#.VAnaWvmSzYF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, Add a `<!DOCTYPE>` to your code: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

And when you add `<!DOCTYPE>` your code stop working for all browser, because of a small reason, you were missing to mention "`px`" after `width`  for the other 3 boxes.

Here is the updated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
            width: 1020px;
        }

        #main {
            background-color: black;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%; /*Remove this if you dont want the Black box to be 100% height*/
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #s {
            float: right;
            background-color: red;
            margin-right: 8px;
            margin-top: 8px;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 290px;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 2px solid yellow;
        }

        #k {
            float: right;
            background-color: green;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
            margin-right: 8px;
            width: 500px;
            height: 300px;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 2px solid yellow;
        }

        #v {
            background-color: grey;
            margin-right: 10px;
            float: right;
            width: 486px;
            height: 143px;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 2px solid yellow;
        }

        #d {
            background-color: blue;
            margin-right: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            float: right;
            width: 486px;
            height: 143px;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 2px solid yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="s">salam</div>
        <div id="k">one</div>
        <div id="d">two</div>
        <div id="v">three</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help!!!

Let me know if you still have issue!

Comment: Good catch on the missing `px`.